# Most efficient way to implement 256 bit bitmask in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, bitmask

I am looking to represent a 256 bit number and do some bitwise operations on it. I will need to bitshift left and AND many times like this:

```js
            while(mask <= test){
                if((mask & test) === mask) return 1;

                mask = mask << 1n;
            }
```

For example, if `mask = 0b101` it will match with `0b1010` and `0b10011011`;

What is the fastest way to do this, for test values of 256 bits? I have considered the following:

### BigInt

This is the most natural way. Unfortunately Safari doesn't support this primitive which is what inspired this question. Maybe there is a better way anyways.

### Matrix of 1s and 0s

Maybe the most straightforward but also the least efficient.

### Uint32Array

Could use an array of 8 32-bit elements. Would be nice but has two problems. One, element order is not guaranteed, and two, bit shifting across the entire array will be a huge pain.

### WebAssembly

I really don't want to have to do this.

Is there another way?

Comment: Am I understanding this right, the question is: How to represent 256bit values that allows efficient bitwise operations (shift and AND in particular) ? You only said that the mask can be 256bit, but I assume the value can be as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll add that. The test value is 256 bits long. The mask is actually less than 256 bits to begin with but when testing I left shift it until it is 256.

Comment: What are your constraints? My first thought was that if you can't use BigInt, doing a substring search on a string representation might be the "simplest" solution.

Comment: I'd like it to be as fast as possible, and work on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: I mean it's all tradeoffs. If you implement your own `BigInt` representation then you will have to implement your own shift and AND logic as well, which is a maintenance cost. I would suggest the following: Look at third-party BigInt libraries and see what they are doing. Maybe you can just use one of them. Benchmark the naive string solution, maybe it is "fast enough". And hopefully someone else comes along and has better ideas than me :)